# What does だから、ではないが mean?

Tags: grammar

これからどのような色に変わるのか、それとも透き通ったままでいるのか、「未知」を前にした神の興味がつきることはない。**だから、ではないが。**

I am having trouble understanding what the bolded part means. How should I interpret it? thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

だから、ではないが
≒ だから[という訳ではない](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21747/5010)が
≒ それが理由だという訳ではないが
≒ I don't mean to say that's the reason, though

Example:

> - 彼は運転がうまい。そして彼は鈴鹿市出身だ。だから、という訳ではないが。
> - 彼は鈴鹿市出身だ。だから、ではないが、彼は運転がうまい。

The speaker doesn't want to say "He's a good driver *because* he's from [Suzuka City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suzuka_Circuit)". But the speaker is loosely associating the two facts ("he's from Suzuka" and "he's a good driver"), knowing that's probably a mere coincidence.