# なんなら【何なら】 = なんだったら【何だったら】 -- Why/How do they mean what they mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology

なんなら【何なら】 = なんだったら【何だったら】 == when transliterated, is it [Then what] ?

> [dictionary.goo.ne.jp  なん‐なら【何なら】](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/165921/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89/)  
>   なん‐なら【何なら】 == ［副］ 《「なになら」の音変化》
>   １.  相手が実現を希望していることを仮定する気持ちを表す。 もしよければ。 「― 私のほうからお電話しましょう」
>
> http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/165834/meaning/m0u/ 
>   なん‐だったら【何だったら】  ==  ［連語］ 「何なら」に同じ。   「 ―  先に帰ってもいいですよ」

Does anyone have any idea why/how these mean this? == The meaning is ---  "if you like [wish]"

Is there a similar expression in Jp, English, French, German, Spanish, etc. ?

English expressions like [You know what?] or [For what it's worth] come to mind.

( なんとなれば【何となれば】 means "because" <-- This is curious, too. )

Comment: その「何」は vagueness... この回答がちょっとくらいなら参考になるかもしれません（し、ならないかもしれません）⇒http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21758/9831

Comment: 何となれば just sounds like "if you ask why".

Comment: 「なんだったら」「なんなら」の「なん」は、明鏡の `なに【何】〘代名詞〙
❷ 相手がそれと分かる事物について、名前の代わりに使う語。例のもの。あれ。また、物事を直接的に指すのを避けて遠回しに言う語。「いつもの、何はあるかな」「うちの何が、うるさくてね」「お言葉を返すようでなんですが…」「自分で言うのもなんですが…」` だと思います。その「なん」は「あれ」に言い換えられる（「（もし）あれだったら」とか）ので。でも、「何となれば」の「何」は、これとは違うと思います。「『何か？』となったら」「なぜかというと」っていう意味なので。

Answer (score 3):

According to 三省堂 (Sanseido’s) 大辞林, “何(なん)なら” is a phonetic conversion of “何（なに）なら,” and it means ①“必要があれば – If it is necessary,” “お望みならば- If you wish,” ➁”差し支えることがあれば - If it troubles you,” “お嫌ならば - If you don’t like it.”

It can be used like:

何なら、君の代わりに僕が会議に出席してもいいよ – I can attend the meeting in place of you, if you don’t mind.

何なら言ってみようか - I can be straightforward to you, if you really wish to listen to.

何ならやってごらん – Please do (try) it by yourself, if you wish.

It's analogous to the Englsih usages of "If you wish" and "If you don't mind."

"何なら" is different from “何となれば,” which means “because it’s …” or “It’s the reason why …”