# What does わけでもなく mean here?

Tags: meaning, expressions

> 彼はおこりだすわけでもなく、彼女をじっと見ている。

He has been slapped. I've already read about わけでもない, but I can't make sense of it anyway, here. "Without getting angry" makes sense, but I would say おこりださないで or おこりださずに, then it should be something else. "With no reason to get angry for"? But he has a reason to get angry for. I think I don't get the meaning of わけ here.

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21747/30454

Comment: "It's not like he is angry, but he just stares at her."